# Questions regarding drone components

Tags: hardware, esc, flight-controller, lipo-batteries, recommendations

I am wanting to build an ultra-light manned bi-copter from scratch, but I first must learn about the components, which is why I am here. I am working with a 43kv (24s rated, 192 max Amp) 70kg thrust motor, a 120cm propeller, and a 200A ESC (no BEC). In my research, I have learned that drones additionally need an (U)BEC and a flight-controller board. (U)BECs seem to come in ratings up to 14s.

My questions are:

1. What (U)BEC should I use?
2. If I want 30 minutes of flight time, what battery and how many should I use?
3. What flight-controller should I use?
4. I plan to have the throttle controlled by a slider on the pilot's control stick. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Edit: Hear are the links to the components I mentioned in the first paragraph:

https://mad-motor.com/product/mad-torq-m40-c30-pro-kv43/#

https://mad-motor.com/product/ampx-esc-200a/

https://mad-motor.com/product/47x13in-uav-drone-prop/

Comment: Well, the answers depend *a lot* on what you are trying to do with the bicopter. What kinds of capabilities are you looking to get? By the sound of your component selection so far, especially the 70kg thrust motor/prop?, your project seems to also be kinda out of the scope of "Drones and Model Aircraft"

Comment: Also, considering that it's a manned bi-copter, it wouldn't strictly fit the definition of a drone.

Comment: @ifconfig , Could you refer me to a place or source of information where I can learn more about components? To answer your question, I want to build an aircraft with two propellers. It will attach to the pilot's body like a hiking backpack, and the propellers will be suspended above the pilot (at a safe height, of course). The motors will be mounted on a two-axis gimbal system to orient the motors according to the pilot's input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A BEC is simply a way to create 5v power from the much higher voltage batteries. When you know how many amps your electronics can draw, you can choose an appropriately sized BEC.
2. To run two motors at full power for half an hour you will need 200Ah. The maths is simple, it's just amps * hours. At 24s (90v), that's 18kWh, which is as big as the battery in some electric cars. If you were to use hobby style batteries, you could use 40 of [these 6s 20Ah lipos](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-high-capacity-battery-20000mah-6s-12c-drone-lipo-pack-xt90.html)
3. I don't think I'd recommend any hobby-grade flight controller for a manned aircraft. The FC is flight-critical, if it goes wrong you will crash. Manned aircraft typically have at least three redundant systems, which compare their outputs so if one develops a fault the other two can 'out vote' it. For really important stuff, there is even more redundancy. Needless to say, there's nothing like this in the hobby world.
4. That should be relatively easy.